# equation number does not appear

Tags: equations, numbering

i wrote in an equation environment, however, the right equation number is not displayed!
it displays (2.1), which is wrong because this is my first equation. I think it took the section number as a first value.

Any idea how to solve this?

my code:

```
\begin{equation}
      \overrightarrow { \rm \nabla }  \cdot [\varepsilon \overrightarrow{ \rm (r)} \nabla \varphi \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) }] = - \frac{1}{\varepsilon_0} \left [ \rho^{fixed} \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) } + e \sum_{i}^{n} C_{i}^{b} exp ( - \frac{ez_i}{kT} \varphi \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) } ) \right ]
 \end{equation}
```

Comment: it is impossible to test a fragment, please show a complete small document that has the problem. note that `\rm` has not been defined in latex by default since 1993.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
      \overrightarrow { \rm \nabla }  \cdot [\varepsilon \overrightarrow{ \rm (r)} \nabla \varphi \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) }] = - \frac{1}{\varepsilon_0} \left [ \rho^{fixed} \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) } + e \sum_{i}^{n} C_{i}^{b} exp ( - \frac{ez_i}{kT} \varphi \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) } ) \right ]
 \end{equation}
\end{document}`  runs without error and makes [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYkVT.png)

Comment: Your document class presumably numbers equations within sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you either defined it in the beginning of your document or you use a document class that specifies it itself accordingly. Anyhow, you can use the `chngcntr` package to manually define how the counting is done.

Here an MWE with the numbering done without the section number:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}

This is some text in Section 1.

\section{Section Two}

This is some text in Section 2. And here comes your equation:
\begin{equation}
      \overrightarrow { \rm \nabla }  \cdot [\varepsilon \overrightarrow{ \rm (r)} \nabla \varphi \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) }] = - \frac{1}{\varepsilon_0} \left [ \rho^{fixed} \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) } + e \sum_{i}^{n} C_{i}^{b} exp ( - \frac{ez_i}{kT} \varphi \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) } ) \right ]
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And here an MWE with the numbering done with the section number:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}

This is some text in Section 1.

\section{Section Two}

This is some text in Section 2. And here comes your equation:
\begin{equation}
      \overrightarrow { \rm \nabla }  \cdot [\varepsilon \overrightarrow{ \rm (r)} \nabla \varphi \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) }] = - \frac{1}{\varepsilon_0} \left [ \rho^{fixed} \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) } + e \sum_{i}^{n} C_{i}^{b} exp ( - \frac{ez_i}{kT} \varphi \overrightarrow{ \rm (r) } ) \right ]
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you all for your input. it worked fine with "\usepackage{chngcntr}"

Comment: You should be aware that about four years ago the `chngcntr` package functionality was incorporated in the LaTeX kernel. Besides, `\rm` has been deprecated for almost 30 years and should not be used.

Comment: @egreg is right, so you do not have to load the `chngcntr` package, you can simply use `\counterwithout{equation}{section}` directly as well

Comment: @KhalidHelmy: If the answer solved your problem, you may want to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark